# Apache returning null for environment variables in header

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2.4, mod-headers

I am trying to troubleshoot my apache test site right now.  I need to have the mod_rewrite variables returned in the header so that I can see what is going on.  However, when I try to set them in the header, I get null

Server version: Apache/2.4.51 (Fedora)

**config**

```
<VirtualHost mysite.local:80>
  ServerName mysite
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mysite
  Header always set TestHeader "%{SERVER_NAME}e"
```

**output from curl**

`curl -I http://mysite.local/index.html`

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 01 Feb 2022 02:05:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.51 (Fedora)
TestHeader: (null)
Last-Modified: Tue, 25 Jan 2022 19:37:28 GMT
ETag: "15-5d66d372009de"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 21
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Also, mod_headers and mod_rewrite are enabled

```
$ grep -R 'mod_rewrite' conf.modules.d/
conf.modules.d/00-base.conf:LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

```
$ grep -R 'mod_headers' conf.modules.d/
conf.modules.d/00-base.conf:LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

Am I missing some setting or configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `PassEnv SERVER_NAME` before the `Header set`.

See [PassEnv - mod_env - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4 Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#passenv) for more info

Comment: I did that, didn't work

Comment: @user2446214 maybe SERVER_NAME is actually not set while you are adding headers.